# Complex QueryBuilder expresion in createQuery() with Sonata Admin

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony 4.2 and Sonata Admin bundle and I'm trying to display a specific list in one of my admin list view.

I want to display the lastest user by group. I created the SQL query and I'm now trying to translate it to QueryBuilder.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (created_at, group_id) IN (
    SELECT MAX(created_at), group_id 
    FROM users
    GROUP BY group_id)
```

My createQuery function in my Sonata Admin class :

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $expr = $em->getExpressionBuilder();


    $subQuery = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('MAX(c.createdAt), c.group')
        ->from('ApiBundle:Configuration', 'c')
        ->groupBy('c.group')
        ->getDQL();

    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $alias = $query->getRootAlias();
    $query->where($expr->in('('.$alias.'.createdAt, '.$alias.'.group)', $subQuery));
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working and I'm not sure it's the right way to do it.
I could make it work with only selecting the createdAt in the in() expression but it's not what I want to have at the end.

Here is the error I got.

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

How can I make it work using QueryBuilder ?
Thank you.

Comment: I think `->select('MAX(c.createdAt), c.group')` should be `->select('MAX(c.createdAt)', 'c.group')` or `->select(['MAX(c.createdAt)', 'c.group'])` (I believe both are acceptable)

Comment: Thank. What about the $expr->in() expression ?

Comment: Yeh, try an array for that too. `$expr->in([$alias.'.createdAt', $alias.'.group'])`